# Using a function as a parameter to another function

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

```
"use strict";
function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
function add(square,y) {
    return square(4) +y
    document.write(square + y)
}
add(4,1);
console.log(add(4,1));
```

I have to use a function as in the parameter of another function. I am trying to output 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it as such:

`add(square,1);`

you may also want to change

```
function add(square,y) {
    return square(4) +y
    document.write(square + y)
}
```

to be:

```
function add(square,y) {
    document.write(square(4) + y)        
    return square(4) +y
}
```

Per Andrew's comment, it might also be a good choice to change `document.write` calls to be `console.log` and open the browser console to read results.

Comment: Also add that `document.write` *is highly discouraged*.

Comment: true, you can [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) about why @AndrewL.is saying that.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew I find this concept quite confusing could you recommend any tutorials that actually  teach this

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to visualize if you change the argument name in your function declaration to be more generic but also more identifiable as a function requirement.

The name you use here is not relevant to the name of the function you will actually pass in

```
function add(func, num) {
    document.write(func(4) + num);
    return func(4) + num;    
}

add(square,1);
```

Then in another call you might do

```
add(myOtherCalcFunction, 6);
```